# EU vehicle (used) - Registration Certificate - registering in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, eu, vehicle-registration

I understand that the owner of a used vehicle, which is brought in the UK from the EU, needs to submit (inter alia) the vehicle's original Registration Certificate from their country of origin, in order to be issued a logbook / V5C from DVLA and register it under British number plates.

Can they still drive the vehicle, while they wait for the DVLA logbook to be issued, without having the vehicle's original Registration Certificate on them? The vehicle would be driven on a still valid Registration Certificate and motor insurance, both from their EU country of origin.

At which stage do they have to insure the vehicle with a UK insurer?